# Search game file and increment replace pid#

Tags: python, linux, vim

I have two football text files from two separate leagues that I would like to combine into one. One problem that I foresee being a problem is that the player id numbers are going to overlap. I was hoping to find a simple solution where I would search for lines in the second file beginning with "pid": and add on a constant of 9000 to each associated number. This has been far harder than I thought it would be due to me in no way being a programmer.

I have finally put together a python code that I thought would work but I soon ran into a problem due to whitespaces at the beginning of the line.

Code below

```
import re
out= open('output2.txt','a')
with open('test5.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if '"pid": ' in line:
            first,second = line.split(" ") ##separate "pid": from rest
            temp = re.findall(r'\d+', line) ##extract number from line
            
            s = [str(i) for i in temp] #convert list of ints to int
            res = int("".join(s))  
            
            idn = res + 9000          #increment id# by 9000
            stringb = str(idn)       #convert back to string to be able to output
            Output = first + " " + stringb  ## combine pid and number w space
            out.write(Output + ',\n') #output with comma at the end
            

        else:
            out.write(line)
```

This works just fine if "pid": was at the beginning of the line but there is always whitespace at the beginning of the lines containing these numbers.

The `test.txt` file I was using is shown below.

```
     "pid": 5,
"uakkdk": 585,
"asfkk": 251,
        "pid": 3000,
"dkek": 21,
     "pid": 0,
"dkdd": 13,
        "pid": 0,
"ekek": 48,
        "pid": 2,
"jest": 86,
     "pid": 508,
"Size": 56,
     "pid": 1024
"germ": 16,
        "pid": 600,
```

I first tried using `sed`, `awk`, `vim` but I could never get anywhere due to not being adept at using those tools. I am about to give up but I was hoping someone here could help.

Answer (score 0):

In Vim, you need a single command:

```
:g/^\s*"pid/normal 9000^A
```

- `:g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on each line matching `<pattern>`,
- `^\s*"pid` is our pattern, which matches `"pid` at the beginning of a line with or without whitespace before it,
- `normal <macro>` is our command, which executes the given normal mode `<macro>`,
- `9000^A` is our normal mode macro, which increments the first number on the line by 9000 (`^A` is a literal Ctrl+A, obtained by pressing Ctrl+V then Ctrl+A).

Comment: I need to keep the whitespace because I will eventually use the code to edit an executable json file for a gm football game.

Comment: Well, the way your question is worded makes it seem that you have the "increment by 9000" problem solved and thus that the "variable indenting" problem is what you are struggling with. Either it is a question about text editing, in which case your Python script is irrelevant, or it is a question about Python, in which case the Vim tag and your mention of `sed` and `awk` are irrelevant. Either way, I reduced my answer to only the "increment by 9000" problem.